# How do I setup memcached for a django app on nitrous.io

Tags: django, memcached, nitrousio

I'm trying to setup a django app with memcached. I have the app working via virtualenv on nitrous.io without memcached.

I ran `parts install memcached` which worked fine. python-memcached is also installed in the virtualenv. I tried running:

```
memcached -d -m memory -s $HOME/memcached.sock -P $HOME/memcached.pid
```

which I do on my production server. But I got this error:

```
failed to set rlimit for open files. Try starting as root or requesting smaller maxconns value.
```

The user rights and whatnot are a little out of my scope of knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `parts start memcached` to run the service on Nitrous.IO.

To change the configuration for the memcached package, edit `/home/action/.parts/etc/memcached.conf`.

Comment: no luck with that change. ran the same command and got the same error.

Comment: I've updated it with the proper way to run memcached on Nitrous.IO. You could add the `-c 200` parameter to the command you were using, but we recommend `parts start memcached` to ensure all configurations are loaded.

Comment: i ran the start command. i did it again to be sure and it says memcached is already running. but when I run "memcached -d -m ...." I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I tested `memcached -d -m memory -s $HOME/memcached.sock -P $HOME/memcached.pid -c 200` and it does run, although we recommend using `parts start memcached` instead as it loads the correct configuration file. Try stopping it first with `parts stop memcached`. If all else fails you can always restart the box.

Comment: not sure exactly what happened this time (i thought i tried restarting it) but its working. Thanks!